# Writing IIf expression on RDLC report text box

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2022, rdlc

I have created an rdlc report on Visual Studio 2022 .net framework core 6. And I'm trying to show a textbox which has visibility check via expression:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Sum(Fields!EmpId.Value, "PayslipDS")), False, True)
```

but it giving me an error and I can not run my rdlc report because of this.

Error Fixing in expression.

Comment: What is the exact error text you get?

Comment: That's the main question brother. it do not shows error like compiler. XD

Comment: Well I resolve this issue and now cracking my head on why it does showing me a scroll bar.XD

Comment: A trick here is to test if the expression is working properly, try using a simpler expression such as =True or =False to see if it affects visibility. In addition, if you have solved your issue, you can publish it and mark it so that it can help more people.